# ubuntu package developing trying to overwrite config of other package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, development

I've build a custom debian package with shuold overwrite configs of lightdm (autologin). My install script (debian/install) contains the following lines:

```
lightdm/* /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
```

But I get the following error while installing my custom package:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/AAA (--unpack):
trying to overwrite `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf', which is also in package CCC
dpkg-deb: subprocess paste killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
AAA E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I know i can use the param --force-overwrite to install the package via dpkg. But I want to install it as dependency of an other package. So how can I allow my package to overwrite the config files of other packages?

I tried this but it wont work (debian/rules):

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
   dh $@

override_dh_command:
   dh_command -- --force-overwrite

override_dh_installdeb:
   dh_installdeb -- --force-overwrite
```

I got it. There is only on thing left. Now i can divert the original conf file. But the checksums of my DEBIAN/conffile is invalid so I deleted it. My debian/rules file:

```
overrider dh_installdeb:
    dh_installdeb
    rm debian/mypackage-name/DEBIAN/conffiles
```

I get the follwing warning:

```
Configuration file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-ubuntu.conf'
 ==> Modified (by you or by a script) since installation.
 ==> Package distributor has shipped an updated version.
   What would you like to do about it ?  Your options are:
    Y or I  : install the package maintainer's version
    N or O  : keep your currently-installed version
      D     : show the differences between the versions
      Z     : start a shell to examine the situation
 The default action is to keep your current version.
*** bash.bashrc (Y/I/N/O/D/Z) [default=N] ?
```

How can I remove the warning message?

This is the content of my debian/preinst file:

```
#!/bin/bash
dpkg-divert --add --package mypackage-name --rename --divert /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf.real /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf
```

Content of my debian/install file:

```
lightdm/* /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/
```

Content debian/rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f

%:
    dh $@

override_dh_builddeb:
    dh_builddeb -- -z1

overrider dh_installdeb:
    dh_installdeb
    rm debian/mypackage-name/DEBIAN/conffiles
```

Thanks.

Comment: Anything that's in `debian/rules` is for building the package only, not for installing the package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't. You [divert](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/dpkg-divert.8) them instead. For convenience, what I do is use a helper package like [`config-package-dev`](http://debathena.mit.edu/config-packages/).  With `config-package-dev`, you give your configuration files some specific names, and the installation will automatically do the required diversion.

For example, if your package is named `foo-bar`, then:

1. Your `debian/rules` will have:

   ```
   %:
       dh $@ --with config-package
   ```
2. Your configuration files end with `.foo` (for example, `lightdm/20-lubuntu.conf.foo` is created by your package building process) - the first word of your package name is used for this extension.
3. You have `config-package-dev` in as a Build-Depends in your `debian/control`. For example:

   ```
   Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7.0.0~), config-package-dev (>= 5.0)
   ```

   This means that `config-package-dev` needs to be installed before you try to build the package, but not for installing.
4. In addition to the `debian/install` file, create a `displace` file listing each file which needs to be diverted. For example, it would contain:

   ```
   /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/20-lubuntu.conf.foo
   ```

Comment: @IHopeLinux I think you missed the warning.

Comment: Ive postet you the message in another answer

Comment: @IHopeLinux Edit it into the question, please. Also, does any of your scripts modify that file? Or has it been modified by other means?

Comment: Its now in the first post. Sorry :) No i am only replacing the original file. But it wont wurk because the conffile-checksums are diferent. I read [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ConfigPackages) i have to remove the DEBIAN/conffile, but now i get this error messige.